# How to narrow the types on an overloaded function with a second optional parameter in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Given an overloaded function where the first parameter can be two types, and the second parameter only exists in one of the variants, how to make the compiler happy when we check the type of the first parameter?

Here's what I tried and the ways it doesn't work. Here's a [link for the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gI1gLngAoBLFABwFcMDMZSBzAGnhAA8MYoaOGBKeALwA+HEiQQQUFAG4AsAChQkWAmTosuAF4ES5Ktzop6AbQC6-YaPGSZChWzJIYWAGYUUYDMVTwXY3ZTU8LQMZrwE2GISUnLyDk6u7p7eKL7+pIEGDMxsHFzBPEbhVtG2cayOzr5JXj5+SAH6BYb08AA+zaGmOeycAPxZRRFRNvAA3grw8MQuRBgAnmQgSLMZVIICAvAA5CFG2-wT8lNTAPSn8ACiAErXAPLXOmSwUAC2IBggMPy5nIOtHXcoBcpBAwEmJzgGAoMFSuBgjQwPTyvFiUwAvnZjvAoTC4VBNIjUQpMfJ7BUEtUPLVUvUAIyI-5hYbWGLkyqJakpNJIBlrIJ7JgsXr5QXFSKssrxKpuLl1MR8vQCwoAzpGMzI-r-cUjKTjCEzOaLZarJUbLa7FXbeAAMhtwpR+uxU1xsJwsERmqgxOxpIh5yutweTxe70+32mSv+7TVJlMENd+MJ-J9fvKHKpyXlSAATIzY8ySjZYtLOVnaWI8-z-l7tSzSiWKTKatz6lWo7GY4KNQ6tbGdZKnVNDYQFksVpHAuadoKDkOTgGACoAC2IaHgAHcnABrdfYdbEDC7eDuFDgEBoNCwYgQebwABuX0iaBAEOHs0Iv2985OOI+ePdBF+S9H1f1JX8MGXGAkA3eAz1gy4YGghFtgAVRQKBsAkeAMCQP8oDAZd4GXL4QAONF4DTF1-zdLQiViUkgA)

```js
declare const bar: (input: string, extra: string) => boolean;
declare const baz: (input: string[]) => boolean;

export function foo(input: string[]): boolean;
export function foo(input: string, extra: string): boolean;
export function foo(input: string | string[], extra?: string): boolean {
  if (typeof input === 'string') {
    // ERROR: (parameter) extra: string | undefined
    return bar(input, extra);
  }

  return baz(input);
}

export function foo1(input: string[]): boolean;
export function foo1(input: string, extra: string): boolean;
export function foo1(input: string | string[], extra?: string): boolean {
  if (typeof input === 'string' && extra) {
    return bar(input, extra);
  }

  // ERROR: (parameter) input: string | string[]
  return baz(input);
}

export function foo2(input: string[]): boolean;
export function foo2(input: string, extra: string): boolean;
export function foo2(input: string | string[], extra?: string): boolean {
  if (typeof input === 'string') {
    // This works but it's unnecessarily verbose
    if (extra) {
      return bar(input, extra);
    }
    throw new Error('Unable to reach here');
  }

  return baz(input);
}
```

Comment: There's no connection _inside_ the function between the types of `input` and `extra`. Something like `return Array.isArray(input) ? baz(input) : bar(input, extra as string);` would do it; you know that the overloads will prevent callers passing anything different.

Comment: What i'm looking for is for a solution without type casting, where TypeScript can infer correctly. I thought overloading gives the relation inside the types?

Comment: The _overload signatures_ are purely for callers of the function; that type information isn't available inside the function, which only uses the _implementation signature_.

Comment: Overloads don't work the way you want.  Even if you could make it work the way you want, though, TS doesn't consider the type of `input` to be a union discriminant, so you'd need some different check.  Observe how `foo2()` works in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NV7Onm).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (Please mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me)